# WFFM: Is it possible to not include attachments with one Send Email save action (but include them with all others)?

Tags: wffm

I have a form that has two Send Email save actions. The first one sends an email to my client, providing them with all of the data that the user submitted in the form. The second one sends a confirmation email to the user. The form includes several file attachment fields. The attachments are sent to my client (which we want) but are also sent to the user (sending them the same files they just submitted, which we don't want). Is it possible to turn off attachments for one Send Email action?

(Using WFFM version 2.3, Sitecore 6.5)

Answer (score 1):

You need to duplicate the **Send Email Message** Save Action and add `<IsIncludeAttachments>false</IsIncludeAttachments>` to the **Parameters** field, for example:

[image: Send Email with Attachment]

Then in your Form use this new "Send Email Message without Attachment" action when you want to send an email to the user and not include any attachments which they may have uploaded.